# When I run my code in R it works, but if I try to knit it into a pdf, it just fails

Tags: r, knitr

I have been trying to get the code below to knit. This is for a lab so it isn't much code.

```
plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + geom_point()
abline(lm(cars$speed ~ cars$dist), col ="red")

cor(cars$speed, cars$dist, use="complete.obs")
myVector = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
MyFunction <- function(x) {
  y <- x*5
  return(y)
}

MyFunction(myVector)
```

Error:

> Error in value [[3L]] (cond) : invalid graphics states Calls:  ... TryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->

Comment: Does it work work if you put the `abline()` directly after `plot()`?

Answer (score 0):

By putting the `abline()` directly after `plot()` I get it to knit a pdf

```
library(ggplot2)

plot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
abline(lm(cars$speed ~ cars$dist), col ="red")

ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + geom_point()

cor(cars$speed, cars$dist, use="complete.obs")
myVector = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

MyFunction <- function(x) {
y <- x*5
return(y)
}

MyFunction(myVector)
```

Comment: Thx That ended up working for me.